# Find Missing Row using SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a table `TRANSACTIONS` with a columns:

```
TRANSACTIONKEY (int) Primary Key
TRANSACTIONTYPEKEY (int) 
RECEIPTNUMBER (varchar)
```

`TRANSACTIONTYPEKEY` can have values that range from 1 to 50.  There **MUST** be a `TRANSACTIONS` row with a `TRANSACTIONTYPEKEY` = 1 and then there can be any number of other `TRANSACTIONTYPEKEY` entries - even duplicates of some (another question for another time).

I have been asked to provide a report that shows all receipts (`RECEIPTNUMBER`) that have entry for `TRANSACTIONTYPEKEY` = 50 **but no `TRANSACTIONTYPEKEY` entry = 1**.   Management has identified a half dozen by accident and wants to know the full extent and this table holds nearly 50,000 rows of transactions.

Is this possible with SQL?  I am using SQL Server 2000 and T-SQL to be specific.

I have tried

```
SELECT RECEIPTNUMBER 
FROM   TRANSACTIONS 
WHERE  TRANSACTIONTYPEKEY = 50 
AND    TRANSACTIONTYPEKEY NOT IN (SELECT TRANSACTIONTYPEKEY FROM TRANSACTIONS WHERE TRANSACTIONTYPEKEY <> 1)
```

but this query goes on and on!  I have to cancel it.

Comment: How many rows are you dealing with?  Have you looked at your execution plan?  If so does it identify any problem areas?

Comment: Do you mean WHERE  TRANSACTIONKEY = 50  or WHERE TRANSACTIONTYPEKEY = 50? Code and text do not match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.RECEIPTNUMBER  
    FROM TRANSACTIONS  a
 WHERE a.TRANSACTIONTYPEKEY = 50  
   AND  NOT EXISTS
                (
                    SELECT 1 
                      FROM TRANSACTIONS b
                     WHERE b.RECEIPTNUMBER = a.RECEIPTNUMBER 
                       AND b.TRANSACTIONTYPEKEY = 1
                )
```

Comment: You were a few seconds quicker. :) +1

Comment: ...too quick to actually read the question. OP mentions TRANSACTIONTYPEKEY filters. Their code does not do this though: neither does this answer. Will it actually help...?

Comment: @gbn: Thx. I have modified the query. I copied the query posted by OP and then changed it. Hence it had TransactionType instead of TransactionTypeKey

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry for the delay, I had to urgently leave work.  But this works and I appreciate the replies!

Answer (score 1):

Assume the filter is on TRANSACTIONTYPEKEY and the JOIN is on TRANSACTIONKEY

```
SELECT T1.RECEIPTNUMBER 
FROM   TRANSACTIONS T1
WHERE
     T1.TRANSACTIONTYPEKEY = 50 
AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TRANSACTIONS T2
                       WHERE T2.RECEIPTNUMBER = T1.RECEIPTNUMBER --oops. fixed
                          T2.TRANSACTIONTYPEKEY > 1)
```

Comment: TRANSACTIONKEY is defined as primary key hence the query above will always return the transactions that have TRANSACTIONTYPEKEY = 50

Comment: @Cybernate: OP states "I have been asked to provide a report that shows all receipts (RECEIPTNUMBER) that have entry for TRANSACTIONTYPEKEY = 50 but no TRANSACTIONTYPEKEY entry = 1"

Comment: True. But will the query that you have posted do that? I don't think so given the fact that TRANSACTIONKEY is a PRIMERY KEY and your subquery join is being done on that field.

Comment: @Cybernate: oops, corrected. Thanks. Guess I should have *thought* as well as *read*...